# How to create recurring invoice with multiple customers in openerp?

Tags: python, xml, openerp-7, invoice, recurring

I am working on openerp7.0. I am stuck up on understanding recurring invoice.

There is an addons called recurring documents in openerp7.0 but I don’t know how to generate periodic invoice for multiple customers using a button?

Comment: You may also check out recurring invoice in odoo from here http://odedrabhavesh.blogspot.in/2014/12/how-to-create-recurring-invoice-in-odoo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this steps for OpenERP v7:

1. Install this module `Recurring Documents` after than you will see the `Tools` in main menu and click on that.
2. Now create a Document Types with Name = Invoice and Object = Invoice and save it.
3. Move to Recurring Events => Subscriptions and create a record with Source Document => Invoice and beside drop-down gives you list of invoices, so select with you want to create with Interval Unit like you want to create that invoices repeatedly like daily, weekly or monthly and save it.
4. Click Process button. It will create Cron Job and makes sure Cron Job has Number of Calls -1.
5. Cron Job will give all details like from now when next document will create.